# How to rowbind two dataframes using a third dataframe to match column names?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(letter = c("A", "B", "C"),
                  number = c(3, 2, 1),
                  rating = c(32, 89, 23))
df2 <- data.frame(lttr = c("D", "E", "F"),
                  mark = c(67, 32, 90),
                  nmbr = c(4, 5, 6))
```

Then I have a third dataframe that specifies which columns match:

```
df3 <- data.frame(df1 = c("letter", "number", "rating"),
                  df2 = c("lttr", "nmbr", "mark"))
```

I want to rowbind `df1` and `df2` by column as specified in `df3`. So the result should be this:

```
df4 <- data.frame(letter = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
                  number = c(3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6),
                  rating = c(32, 89, 23, 67, 32, 90))
```

What is the easiest way to do this? I thought maybe by `dplyr::full_join()` but don't know how to specify the column names that should match.

Edit: This is a simplified example. My real df1 and df2 have 50 columns. I would like to prevent having to write for every column in df1 what is the matching column name in df2, since this information is already enclosed in df3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are attempting here is not a 'join' - you're just binding the rows of these data frames. You just need to change the column names of df2, then call `base::rbind()`

This should work:

```r
## Get column 'df1' from 'df3', but ordered 
## such that column 'df2' matches the names of 'df2'

new_names <- df3[["df1"]][match(df3[["df2"]], names(df2))]

new_names
#> [1] "letter" "rating" "number"

## rename df2
names(df2) <- new_names

## Bind the two data frames by row
df4 <- rbind(df1, df2)

## (NB to preserve columns from df1, instead use)
## df4 <- plyr::rbind.fill(df1, df2) 

df4
#>   letter number rating
#> 1      A      3     32
#> 2      B      2     89
#> 3      C      1     23
#> 4      D      4     67
#> 5      E      5     32
#> 6      F      6     90
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This works - Thanks! But... what if  df1 would have another column that does not match with anything in df2, but would have to be retained anyway? In that case, would you resort to a full_join?

Comment: @Lieke that still wouldn't be a join - joins add new rows (and potentially columns) to data on the basis of matching fields, whereas you're adding new rows on the basis of matched column names. You might need to ask your follow-up question separately - things can get messy when the scope of an existing question increases

Comment: @Lieke I've just done a bit of research, and it sounds like `dplyr::bind_rows()` does what you want. Check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dave-lovell/b2b75dc308387a06139b46f3a3aebfad) for a tiny demo.

Comment: bind_rows() works indeed, and I found another option myself: plyr::rbind.fill()

Comment: @Lieke that will work, but please note that `plyr` has been retired, and its creators now recommend that you instead use `dplyr`. `bind_rows()` is the `dplyr` equivalent of `rbind.fill()`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to convert `df3` to a named vector which makes things a bit simpler:

```r
df3 <- data.frame(df1 = c("letter", "number", "rating"),
                  df2 = c("lttr", "nmbr", "mark"))
name_vec <- setNames(df3$df1, df3$df2)
names(df2) <- name_vec[names(df2)]

names(df2)
#> [1] "letter" "rating" "number"

df4 <- rbind(df1, df2)
df4
#>   letter number rating
#> 1      A      3     32
#> 2      B      2     89
#> 3      C      1     23
#> 4      D      4     67
#> 5      E      5     32
#> 6      F      6     90
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` way using pipes and without creating temporary variables can be -

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% bind_rows(df2 %>% rename(!!df3 %>% pull(df2, df1)))

#  letter number rating
#1      A      3     32
#2      B      2     89
#3      C      1     23
#4      D      4     67
#5      E      5     32
#6      F      6     90
```

---

**Explanation -**

`pull` creates a named vector.

```
df3 %>% pull(df2, df1)

# letter number rating 
#"lttr" "nmbr" "mark"
```

which is used in `rename` to change the column names of `df2`.

```
df2 %>% rename(!!df3 %>% pull(df2, df1))

#  letter rating number
#1      D     67      4
#2      E     32      5
#3      F     90      6
```

Finally, the above output is row binded with `df1`.

```
df1 %>% bind_rows(df2 %>% rename(!!df3 %>% pull(df2, df1)))

#  letter number rating
#1      A      3     32
#2      B      2     89
#3      C      1     23
#4      D      4     67
#5      E      5     32
#6      F      6     90
```

Comment: What is the `!!` before `df3` doing?